# Detecting shakes in sprite kit

Tags: sprite-kit, shake, skscene

I have a problem with detecting a shake. It's a skscene in the Sprit Kit and I defined the motion detector like this:

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}

-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

NSLog(@"test?");

}
```

Where is my mistake? Do I have to implement it like I had to do it with the UIGestureRecognizer?

Thanks in advance (and sorry for my bad english)
Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you can't detect shake events from a `SKScene` subclass, such as `GameScene`. However, you can detect them from a view controller, such as `GameViewController`. When a shake event is triggered, you can call a shake handler in `GameScene` from the view controller.

In your GameViewController.m, add this to detect shake events

```
- (void) motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
        GameScene *scene = (GameScene *)skView.scene;
        // Call a function in the GameScene
        [scene shake];
    }
}
```

Add this to the @interface in GameScene.h

```
- (void) shake;
```

Add this to GameScene.m

```
- (void) shake {
    NSLog(@"shake");
}
```