# Why isn't func motionEnded not working in GameScene?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a title screen on a game I'm trying to learn making and want to add a feature that responds to a user shaking. The function works when put standalone but not on this page. By not working I mean it appears to do nothing (won't even print to the logs).

The function in question is motionEnded func.

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import iAd

class GameScene: SKScene {

    //loud soundfiles
    var titleMusic = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Loping Sting", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlayNow")
    let titleScreen = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Title")
    let titleOrange = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        //stop music from game
        musicPlayer.stop()

        //play sound file
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: titleMusic, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()

        self.titleScreen.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 100)
        self.addChild(self.titleScreen)
        self.addChild(self.playButton)

        //animate button
        let pulseUp = SKAction.scaleTo(1.1, duration: 0.9)
        let pulseDown = SKAction.scaleTo(0.7, duration: 0.9)
        let pulse = SKAction.sequence([pulseDown, pulseUp])
        let repeatPulse = SKAction.repeatActionForever(pulse)
        self.playButton.runAction(repeatPulse)

        //show hero
        titleOrange.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 363)
        self.addChild(titleOrange)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton {
                var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
                let skView = self.view as SKView?
                scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
                scene.size = skView!.bounds.size
                skView?.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
    }

    override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if motion == .MotionShake {
            println("Shake")
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting shakes in sprite kit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679491/detecting-shakes-in-sprite-kit)

Answer (score 1):

Since you had it working previously, I presume you have `applicationSupportsShakeToEdit` set to `true` (this is the default anyway).

You then need to ensure that your scene `GameScene` becomes the first responder - the first responder will (as the name implies) be the first to be given the opportunity to respond to motion events, and after that it progresses up the [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2). `SKScene` conforms to the `UIResponder` protocol, so you just need to allow it to become first responder by overriding a method, and then call a couple of responder methods when the scene appears/disappears:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // ...
    becomeFirstResponder()
}

override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    // ...
    resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Note that making your scene the first responder *may* affect other event handling code elsewhere in your app, depending on your app's structure.

Comment: I included applicationSupportsShakeToEdit now inside my app delegate. I've also added those three functions. Still no response from the app (simulator and device). Any other avenue you suggest?

Comment: @Frankeex After further research, it would appear that you can't detect shake events from an `SKScene`, which strikes me as odd and I can't find a reason in the documentation. You will have to use another object - such as the view controller managing the scene - to detect the shake gesture, and perhaps call a method on your scene if necessary.

Comment: thank you. Appreciate your time and assistance and will get that implemented.